# Nothing's getting done today - is it present or future?

Tags: tenses, ing, continuous-aspect

Is the sentence "Nothing's getting done today" present continuous?

Why is the verb *get* ending in "-ing"?

Comment: Please see also [ell.se]

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to treat *'s* as *was*, so yes, it is the present continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is present continuous.  I am prepared to try to defend my response.